# Beacon receiver control

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, beacon, eddystone

Is there a way to track which devices got a notification broadcasted by a beacon? Reason I'm wondering is I would like to leverage nearby device communication, but not flood people that are often at a specific location with the same message over and over again (putting leverage into irritation/anger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your own app to receive the beacon transmissions and send the messaging to the user, then yes you can do this.  The typical approach is to simply call a web service API on message delivery that inserts a row into a database on a server (typically including a timestamp and info about the message sent to the user,  often also including some kind of app installation id (or user identifier like email) so you can see how many times the same user received different messages.

Beacons by themselves, however, won't do this, because they are one-way transmitters with no knowledge of what devices receive their transmissions.

Comment: Thanks for the clearity. I think I won't be able to create what I had in mind. (drop a beacon in my car, keep track of devices that were nearby and got a message, and not bother them for say 30 days if they are nearby inbetween. This mostly because of my coworkers, which are also parked in the same garage every day ;) (large company: 4k emp.))